# R - When defining a new list, is it possible to assign a character variable to its names?

Tags: r, list

If I want to define a new list `L=list(x=1)` with x in a character variable I can run this

```
s = 'x'
L = list(1)
names(L) = s
```

Is there any simpler way to do it (in one line)? Note the name `'x'` is dynamic and saved in a variable `s` that I can't use it directly.

Comment: The name 'x' is dynamic (determined by a character variable)

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I need.